# SQL Convert String to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to find a way of extracting the first part of line of string and separating as a date.  The following is an example of some of the data.

```
17/10/12 lskell Still waiting for one more signature on the
```

I have tried casting the whole field as a date, and converting to a date, but these fail?

Would anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for MySql

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(columnname,' ',1), '%d/%m/%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

(assuming date comes in this format)

```
-- MYSQL:

SELECT Str_to_Date(Left(yourstring,8),'%d/%m/%y') from yourtable;

-- Oracle

SELECT TO_DATE(left(yourstring,8),'dd/mm/yy')
from your table;

--- sql server
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,left(yourstring,8),120) from your table;
```

Comment: Check on this as well http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/ and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you know that

- the first "word" in your string will *always* be a date
- the date will *always* be separated from the rest of the string by a space
- the date will have a consistent format
- you are working in MySQL

then try this:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(myfield, ' ', 1) AS DATE) adate FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('10/17/12 lskell Still waiting for one more signature on the', 1, 8)
```